# "Project's status" or "project status"

Tags: possessives, compounds

Should I say *the project's status* or *the project status*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Project's status* would be preferable in speech and formal writing, meaning the status of this particular project.

Ex: *What's the project's status at this point?*

If you were preparing a form or spreadsheet and the status of the project were a data point, *project status* would be an appropriate heading for the entry.

Ex:

*Project Name: Take Over World*

*Project Start Date: Yesterday*

*Project Status: In progress*

Answer (score 5):

"The project's status" is correct, as it is the status of the project you are talking about.

"Project Status" is also used, but normally as a headline or bullet point as it is not grammatically correct in a sentence.